# Worksheet function to check if cell contains only characters as defined in a constant string

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, string

I have this string constant: `abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890' -`

Now for each cell in column A I want to check, in column B, with a worksheet function, not a Macro, if that cell contains only characters from the constant string. If any other characters than are defined in the string constant occur, I want to print "invalid char" in column B.

Comment: Where does column A fit in?  Do the cells in column A each contain the string to be used for evaluating the associated cell in column B?

Answer (score 0):

As you have to go character by character of the contents on each cell of column A it is very difficult to make without a macro.

It will need a lot of  helper columns, and the nesting of functions inside each formula will make very hard to maintain.

Comment: Answers should really be reserved for complete solutions (or a definitive explanation of why a solution isn't possible).  General advice that isn't either, like this post, should be done in a comment.